# Install ffmpeg in Ubuntu 12.04 LTS

Tags: 12.04, ffmpeg

**Background :**

I used `ffmpeg` to merge two videos side by side. First I install ffmpeg by following command as it suggest by Ubuntu itself.

```
sudo apt-get install libav-tools
```

or

```
sudo apt-get install ffmpeg
```

But then I realize it is not the correct version since it doesn't support for `-filter_complex` and few other functions.

After a few hours researcher I found [real ffmpeg](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/UbuntuCompilationGuide) and I succeed with video conversion as well. As per that article, it is suggesting we need to build it our own.

> https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/UbuntuCompilationGuide

**Question :**

What is easiest way to install that `ffmpeg version` (which is support for `-filter_complex` ) without following all those steps ?

Comment: Do you insist on using ffmpeg for merging two videos or a better tool having a GUI will be fine?

Comment: I need to do it in programmatic way not manually. I have tried `gstreamer` as well.

Comment: You can try this builds already compiled: http://ffmpeg.gusari.org/static/

Comment: alternatively, I suggest WinFF http://winff.org/html_new/ which supports ffmpeg command line

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The ffmpeg versions available in the Ubuntu repositories may not be up to date. Therefore, if you want the latest features, download the latest `ffmpeg` static build (32/64) with given link and follow the instructions.

> http://johnvansickle.com/ffmpeg/

- Download and extract the latest archive:

  ```
  wget https://johnvansickle.com/ffmpeg/builds/ffmpeg-git-64bit-static.tar.xz
  tar xvf ffmpeg-git-*.tar.xz
  ```
- Place the `ffmpeg` and other binaries whereever you need to run that command, for example into `/usr/local/bin` in order to have it to your `$PATH`:

  ```
  cd ./ffmpeg-git-*
  sudo cp ff* qt-faststart /usr/local/bin/
  ```
- Run ffmpeg using: `ffmpeg`

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/a/884683/237607