# problem in installing ffmpeg in ubuntu 14.04

Tags: apt, ffmpeg

I try to install ffmpeg in Ubuntu 
according to https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/CompilationGuide/Ubuntu 
 I create a shell file with below code

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get -y install autoconf automake build-essential libass-dev libfreetype6-dev libgpac-dev \
  libsdl1.2-dev libtheora-dev libtool libva-dev libvdpau-dev libvorbis-dev libx11-dev \
  libxext-dev libxfixes-dev pkg-config texi2html zlib1g-dev
mkdir ~/ffmpeg_sources

cd ~/ffmpeg_sources
wget http://download.videolan.org/pub/x264/snapshots/last_x264.tar.bz2
tar xjvf last_x264.tar.bz2
cd x264-snapshot*
PATH="$PATH:$HOME/bin" ./configure --prefix="$HOME/ffmpeg_build" --bindir="$HOME/bin" --enable-static --disable-opencl
PATH="$PATH:$HOME/bin" make
make install
make distclean

sudo apt-get install unzip
cd ~/ffmpeg_sources
wget -O fdk-aac.zip https://github.com/mstorsjo/fdk-aac/zipball/master
unzip fdk-aac.zip
cd mstorsjo-fdk-aac*
autoreconf -fiv
./configure --prefix="$HOME/ffmpeg_build" --disable-shared
make
make install
make distclean


cd ~/ffmpeg_sources
wget http://ffmpeg.org/releases/ffmpeg-snapshot.tar.bz2
tar xjvf ffmpeg-snapshot.tar.bz2
cd ffmpeg
PATH="$PATH:$HOME/bin" PKG_CONFIG_PATH="$HOME/ffmpeg_build/lib/pkgconfig" ./configure \
  --prefix="$HOME/ffmpeg_build" \
  --extra-cflags="-I$HOME/ffmpeg_build/include" \
  --extra-ldflags="-L$HOME/ffmpeg_build/lib" \
  --bindir="$HOME/bin" \
  --enable-libfdk-aac \
  --enable-libx264 \
PATH="$PATH:$HOME/bin" make
make install
make distclean
hash -r
```

(I add execution permission to this file ) and in command line run  ./mybashfile.sh)

it run correctly and start to download but some last line of terminal output is

```
.
.
.
rm -f libMpegTPEnc/src/.dirstamp
rm -f libPCMutils/src/.deps/.dirstamp
rm -f libPCMutils/src/.dirstamp
rm -f libSBRdec/src/.deps/.dirstamp
rm -f libSBRdec/src/.dirstamp
rm -f libSBRenc/src/.deps/.dirstamp
rm -f libSBRenc/src/.dirstamp
rm -f libSYS/src/.deps/.dirstamp
rm -f libSYS/src/.dirstamp
rm -f libtool config.lt
rm -f TAGS ID GTAGS GRTAGS GSYMS GPATH tags
rm -f cscope.out cscope.in.out cscope.po.out cscope.files
rm -f config.status config.cache config.log configure.lineno config.status.lineno
rm -rf ./.deps libAACdec/src/.deps libAACenc/src/.deps libFDK/src/.deps libMpegTPDec/src/.deps libMpegTPEnc/src/.deps libPCMutils/src/.deps libSBRdec/src/.deps libSBRenc/src/.deps libSYS/src/.deps
rm -f Makefile
--2014-09-07 15:18:35--  http://ffmpeg.org/releases/ffmpeg-snapshot.tar.bz2
Resolving ffmpeg.org (ffmpeg.org)... 192.190.173.45
Connecting to ffmpeg.org (ffmpeg.org)|192.190.173.45|:80... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK
Length: unspecified [text/html]
Saving to: ‘ffmpeg-snapshot.tar.bz2’

    [ <=>                                   ] 13          --.-K/s   in 0s      

2014-09-07 15:18:45 (1.30 MB/s) - ‘ffmpeg-snapshot.tar.bz2’ saved [13]

bzip2: (stdin) is not a bzip2 file.
tar: Child returned status 2
tar: Error is not recoverable: exiting now
./install-ffmpeg.sh: line 31: cd: ffmpeg: No such file or directory
./install-ffmpeg.sh: line 32: ./configure: No such file or directory
make: *** No rule to make target `install'.  Stop.
make: *** No rule to make target `distclean'.  Stop.
```

**where is the Problem? and how Can I install ffmpeg correctly?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way is to [download one of the static builds](http://johnvansickle.com/ffmpeg/) linked from the [FFmpeg download page](http://ffmpeg.org/download.html).

You can then run it with

```
$ /opt/ffmpeg-2.3.3-64bit-static/ffmpeg
```

(or wherever you expanded the archive to).

Answer (score 0):

Here is a sample script to Install ( Download/Extract/Put in user `bin` PATH directory ) [latest](https://www.johnvansickle.com/ffmpeg/) `ffmpeg` static version:

```
wget https://johnvansickle.com/ffmpeg/releases/ffmpeg-release-64bit-static.tar.xz
tar -xvJf  ffmpeg-release-64bit-static.tar.xz  --strip-components=1 -C ./usr/bin
```