# How to install ffmpeg on ubuntu?

Tags: 12.04, ffmpeg, nginx, rtmp

For transcoding video I need to use ffmpeg. I have tried to install but I have faced with problems. Is anyone that can help  with this case or can anyone offer any weblink or guide where I can follow the steps for correct installation?

Comment: have you tried `sudo apt-get install ffmpeg`

Comment: Have you tried this 
http://askubuntu.com/questions/432542/is-ffmpeg-missing-from-the-official-repositories-in-14-04

Comment: You write that there were problems. What are the problems?

Comment: Try the solution given here: https://askubuntu.com/questions/426543/install-ffmpeg-in-ubuntu-12-04-lts?rq=1

Comment: I have installed all dependencies and libraries.Later when I come to install ffmpeg, I have no problems with configuration and make process, but I am facing problems with checkinstall process.

Answer (score 9):

The best way to install is by a repo, this way you can stay upto date easily.

I see you use 12.04 and it is for 14.04 but they might work anyway, however an upgrade would be a good idea as 14.04 is also an LTS.

To install FFmpeg in Ubuntu/Linux Mint open Terminal (Press Ctrl+Alt+T) and copy the following commands in the Terminal:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:kirillshkrogalev/ffmpeg-next
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install ffmpeg
```

Comment: -1, the PPA does not seem to be maintained anymore and this will install an outdated version of ffmpeg. Users should rather download a static build from https://ffmpeg.org/download.html

Comment: @slchk If this is true, why down vote a 2 year old answer as out of date? It was correct when it was written. Instead, add another answer containing up to fate information, people may not see a comment.

Comment: If an answer becomes outdated and is unsalvageable, why not downvote it? Downvotes are for posts that aren't useful (anymore), and visitors who happen to find this question will not care about when a specific answer was written.  The correct and up to date answer is given in the duplicate already, so there's no need for another answer.

Comment: Using `sudo add-apt-repository ppa:mc3man/trusty-media` gets me version 3.3.3. Current one is 3.3.4. Not bad.

Comment: I think its better if you put a heading to your answer saying its outdated and refer to appropriate comment. @slhck would that be acceptable?

Comment: @NagabhushanSN That'd be an interim solution. The answer should just be deleted IMO.